# Not able to see scheduled tasks from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-task

Since upgrading to windows 7 I am no longer able to see scheduled tasks on a remote computer accessed by a UNC path (ie: \\mymachinename). Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

well another way is opening task scheduler on your windows 7 machine and then right click on 'Task Scheduler Local' and the select connect to another computer.

[image: Task Scheduler]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to verify using Powershell:

```
<#   
.SYNOPSIS   
    Script that return informations about scheduled tasks on a computer

.DESCRIPTION 
    This script uses the Schedule.Service COM-object to query the local or a remote computer in order to gather a
    formatted list including the Author, UserId and description of the task. This information is parsed from the
    XML attributed to provide a more human readable format

.PARAMETER Computername
    The computer that will be queried by this script, local administrative permissions are required to query this
    information

.NOTES   
    Name: Get-ScheduledTask.ps1
    Author: Jaap Brasser
    DateCreated: 2012-05-23
    DateUpdated: 2012-07-22
    Site: http://www.jaapbrasser.com
    Version: 1.2

.LINK
    http://www.jaapbrasser.com

.EXAMPLE   
    .\Get-ScheduledTask.ps1 -Computername mycomputer1

Description 
-----------     
This command query mycomputer1 and display a formatted list of all scheduled tasks on that computer

.EXAMPLE   
    .\Get-ScheduledTask.ps1

Description 
-----------     
This command query localhost and display a formatted list of all scheduled tasks on the local computer  
#>
```